# Logstash pipeline getting freezed

Tags: logstash

I am new to Elastic Search Logstash and kabana, I have written logstash.conf Here is the glimpse of it

```
input{
 file{
   path=>"C:\Users\mohammadraghib.ahsan\Downloads\Gl\adapterCommon.log"
  start_position=>"beginning"
  sincedb_path => "C:\Users\mohammadraghib.ahsan\Downloads\Gl\sincedb.db"
 }
}

filter{
 grok{
   match => {"message" => "%{DATA:deviceid} %{GREEDYDATA:data}"}
 }
}

output{
   stdout { codec => rubydebug }

}
```

When I am executing it by `.\logstash -f logstash.confg` i am using powershell on windows

It get freezed on this part

[image]

Comment: This does not look frozen but rather like logstash has no access to your log file, therefore there is nothing to parse, therefore there is no output

Comment: The message you've received (`Pipeline main started`) indicates that Logstash has started normally and is waiting for input. So either there is a problem with your log file or the file has already been read (since you've indicated a sincedb_path, Logstash will not read again the file).

Comment: After entering one blank line at the end of input file resolved this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appreciate for the valuable comment provided by pandaadb and baudsp. Adding one blank line at the end of file resolved this issue. THe problem with logstash is that sometimes it fails to run if it found file with same signature(last modified) so adding one last line at the end helped in changing the file signature.